# Sample Facebook integration in iPhone App

Tags: iphone

Does anyone have a good tutorial to implement Facebook in an iPhone app?

Showing a button which links to Facebook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for those who still looking for facebook and twitter implementation

here
for twitter

[link text](http://amanpages.com/sample-iphone-example-project/multiple-login-for-twitteragent/)

for facebook
[link text](http://amanpages.com/sample-iphone-example-project/iphone-facebook-connect-how-do-i-publish-feed-with-facebookagent/)

i hope this is gonna help some people like me...

regards
shishir